# TinyMCE, show character count instead of word count

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, charactercount

The title says it all. How do I get [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/) to show character count instead of word count?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Write your own plugin.

The following solution is based on [this article](https://amystechnotes.com/2015/05/06/tinymce-add-character-count/comment-page-1/). The `charactercount` plugin counts the actual characters that the user sees, all HTML and hidden characters are ignored. The number is updated on every "key up" event.

Character Count Plugin:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('charactercount', function (editor) {
  var self = this;

  function update() {
    editor.theme.panel.find('#charactercount').text(['Characters: {0}', self.getCount()]);
  }

  editor.on('init', function () {
    var statusbar = editor.theme.panel && editor.theme.panel.find('#statusbar')[0];

    if (statusbar) {
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        statusbar.insert({
          type: 'label',
          name: 'charactercount',
          text: ['Characters: {0}', self.getCount()],
          classes: 'charactercount',
          disabled: editor.settings.readonly
        }, 0);

        editor.on('setcontent beforeaddundo', update);

        editor.on('keyup', function (e) {
            update();
        });
      }, 0);
    }
  });

  self.getCount = function () {
    var tx = editor.getContent({ format: 'raw' });
    var decoded = decodeHtml(tx);
    // here we strip all HTML tags
    var decodedStripped = decoded.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, "").trim();
    var tc = decodedStripped.length;
    return tc;
  };

  function decodeHtml(html) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = html;
    return txt.value;
  }
});
```

CSS Tweaks:

```
/* Optional: Adjust the positioning of the character count text. */
label.mce-charactercount {
  margin: 2px 0 2px 2px;
  padding: 8px;
}

/* Optional: Remove the html path code from the status bar. */
.mce-path {
  display: none !important;
}
```

TinyMCE Initialization (using jQuery)

```
$('textarea.tinymce').tinymce({
  plugins: "charactercount",
  statusbar: true,
  init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
    $('.mce-tinymce').show('fast');
    $(editor.getContainer()).find(".mce-path").css("display", "none");
  }
  // ...
});
```

ps. Use JS minifier.

Comment: I tried using this sample. When I walked thru the code, the statusbar variable returned 'undefined' upon getting to the 'if (statusbar) {" line, so naturally that "if" block does not execute. When I tried expanding editor.theme, I could not find a panel object. I am using tinymce ver 5.0.14 because our security people say this is the correct version I need to be using. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Mark please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). And Stack Overflow users will help you. I advise preparing JSFiddle ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/textboxio/tx4Lc8a9/4/)), that clearly demonstrates how to reproduce your problem, and inserting a link to the JSFiddle in your question.

Answer (score 22):

[wordcount](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/wordcount/) plugin now can count and show characters:

> Clicking Word Count in the status bar switches between counting words
>   and characters.

By default mode is "words", but it's pretty easy emulate click in status bar to switch it.

Alter your editor config following way:

```
tinymce.init({
   plugins: "wordcount",

   // ... 

   init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
      $(editor.getContainer()).find('button.tox-statusbar__wordcount').click();  // if you use jQuery
   }
});
```

That's all. You have character count now.

Comment: It's a terrible hack, but it works. IMHO this should be an option in the plugin itself. I can't imagine why anyone would want to count words by default anyhow.

Comment: It works, i didnt find better solution for v5, @naXa solutions dont work

Comment: Yeah.. But it works! And copy/paste done. I needed the character count because we take the body and send it out via SMS sometimes, so it's useful to know the # characters used.

Answer (score 8):

```
    init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
editor.on('change', function (e) {
                var length = editor.contentDocument.body.innerText.length;
            });
}
```

On init add this. length is your character length. Now you need to hide word count and attach a new string with character counter.

Comment: *keyup* will be better

Answer (score 4):

I was able to set the [wordcount](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/wordcount/) plugin to display characters by default by creating a custom version of the silver theme. Looks like in TinyMCE 5.1.6 the way plugins are rendered is set in the theme file. TinyMCE config:

```
{
    selector: '.tinymce',
    theme: 'silver-custom',
    ...
}
```

The theme file is a copy of the themes/silver/theme.js and needs to load after TinyMCE.

Changes:

```
 ...
 function Theme () {
      global$1.add('silver-custom', function (editor) {
 ...
```

and

```
...
var renderWordCount = function (editor, providersBackstage) {
    ...
    store: {
        mode: 'memory',
        initialValue: {
        mode: 'characters',
        ...
}
...
```

Comment: This seems to be the best and easiest way to do this. It also avoids reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one in production https://gist.github.com/imanilchaudhari/5a121ea6420eb4b8aa7ee70a5f7074e3  since 2017. this plugin is good.

I initially thought **charword** count comes with the tinymce builtin plugins, but later found that it is a custom one.

It will show number of character in the bottom status bar

[image]

Comment: That script is old and not working with tinymce 5